# on event target add css tilde from element1 to element2

Tags: javascript, css, dom

basically, how to dynamically perform the following using JS:

`element1:target ~ element2 {//does something}`

```
element1.addEventListener(":target", () => {
   //something here? 
});
```

Or maybe another instance to make it clearer:

```css
.go:checked ~ .road {
  -webkit-animation: move-road 6s 1  1.3s ease-in-out forwards,
                     rotate-road 1s forwards;
}
```

(Source) : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/triggering-css-animations-with-sibling-selectors

Is this JS doable?

Comment: Javascript doesn't really support pseudo-selectors.

Comment: As for siblings and cheking if elements are checked etc. it's all doable in javascript.

Comment: @adeneois there anyway u cud generate d above with js dynamically?

Comment: You can use `.go:target + .road` if the `.road` is immediately after `.go` element

Answer (score 0):

The context of this code relates to a carousel without any plugins. The question wasn't about slider but I am just going to explain how I Instead tried to make it simpler with the following as against my requirements above:

```js
e.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  // e is individual buttons on the slider div 
  let that = this;
  // id = evt.target.hash;
  id = that.href;
  // console.log(id);
  num = parseInt(id[id.length - 1]) * -800;
  slider.style.left = `${num}px`;
});
```

slider is the following class on the css side, where it matters:

```
.div-img-holder
    width: 2400px;
    height: 400px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -o-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;
```

1. I calculated the total div frames to show in one frame of the slider and set the presentable width;
2. Created a slider width as in here i.e. maximum width.
3. On each btn click , the slider goes left by a certain position. the transition takes care of the smooth left movement.

Put the transition and pseudo-css stuff to css.